# Is grailsApplication is predefined

Tags: grails

I have a sample code where they used def  grailsAppication like

```
class ViewSourceController {
  def grailsApplication

  def controllerClass = grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName(
      "Controller", controllerName)
}
```

is grailsApplication is predefined one, will it search in application's directory for required files, I want to know about its usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grailsApplication` is a Spring bean of type [GrailsApplication](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html) that is created by the framework. According to the docs, `GrailsApplication` is:

> the main interface representing a running Grails application. This interface's main purpose is to provide a mechanism for analysing the conventions within a Grails application as well as providing metadata and information about the execution environment.

Refer to [the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html) for more information about the methods provided by `GrailsApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

GrailsApplication is an interface of grails and This interface's main purpose is to provide a mechanism for analysing the conventions within a Grails application as well as providing metadata and information about the execution environment.

The GrailsApplication interface interacts with ArtefactHandler instances which are capable of analysing different artefact types (controllers, domain classes etc.) and introspecting the artefact conventions

Implementors of this inteface should be aware that a GrailsApplication  [here](http://grails.org/doc/1.1/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html)  is only initialised when the initialise() method is called. In other words GrailsApplication instances are lazily initialised by the Grails runtime.